# Making Magento custom module name look a bit better in the system configuration tab

Tags: magento

I have written a custom module, and it's name is listed in the Configuration on the left hand side of the System tab. However, it looks a bit boring just being plain text. The PayPal module appears as an image rather than text. Or it might be text with css applied. Either way, can I alter how my module name looks in the list of configurable modules?

James.

Answer (score 1):

very easy and simple, in your module system.xml under you tab declaration add:

```
<config>
    <section>
        <yoursection ...>
            <class>my-section-class</class>
            <tab>...</tab>
            <label>...</label>
              .
              .
              .
```

where my-section-class is a css class name.

Then put all the stuff in your skin/adminhtml/.../css/yoursection.css and images.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it is not working. I put <class>mymodule-section</class> in system.xml. I created the file skin/adminhtml/default/default/mycompany.css, containing `.mymodule-section {background-image:url('images/mycompany_logo.jpg')};` but my module name still just appears as text. Is the presence of my css file in that folder enough for it to be included? Also, I did not put my css in a folder named css as you mentioned in your post - just because all other css files were in skin/adminhtml/default/default/ rather than skin/adminhtml/default/default/css/.

Comment: You need to have this in you layout in adminhtml                    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>css/yourcssfile.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>

Comment: The css file does not needs to be in css folder if you mention that above in the stylesheet tag... it will however search in your admin skin folder as configured in the backend.

Comment: Sorry (new to this), do you mean in etc/adminhtml.xml in my module?

Comment: in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/yourmodule.xml also in order to make this active you need in your config.xml <adminhtml><layout><updates><yourmodule module='yourmodule'><file>yourmodule.xml</file></yourmodule></updates>... close all tags

Comment: I have been away for a while, but if you still have the patience, may I tell you exactly what I have so that you can hopefully tell me what is wrong -over a few comments due to size restrictions: app/code/local/MyNamespace/MyModule/etc/system.xml
`<config>
  <tabs>
   <mynamespace translate="label" module="mymodule">
    <label>MyNamespace</label>
    <sort_order>301</sort_order>
   </mynamespace>
  </tabs>
  <sections>
   <mymodule translate="label" module="mymodule">
   <label>My Module</label>
   <tab>mynamespace</tab>
   <class>mymodule-section</class>
  </mymodule>
 </sections>
</config>`

Comment: app/code/local/MyNamespace/MyModule/etc/config.xml
`<config>
    <adminhtml> 
 <layout>
  <updates>
   <mymodule>
    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
   </mymodule>
                </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>`

Comment: app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mymodule.xml
`<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
     <reference name="head">
      <action method="addCss">
                 <stylesheet>mynamespace.css</stylesheet>
                </action>
        </reference>
    </default>    
</layout>`

skin/adminhtml/default/default/mynamespace.css
`.mymodule-section {background-image:url('images/mycompany_logo.jpg')};`

skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/mycompany_logo.jpg

Comment: The difference I can see are : on you config xml     <mymodule module="mymodule">...</mymodule> ... the rest looks fine, other than usually the css are in css/... folder. Can you actually see in firebug that that tab button is getting the class name but is not getting styles?